# Passing a 'var' into another method

Tags: c#, asp.net, var

I am probably totally missing the point here but....

How can I pass a 'var' into another method?

(I am using linq to load XML into an Enumerable list of objects).

I have differernt object types (with different fields), but the final step of my process is the same regardless of which object is being used.

```
XNamespace xmlns = ScehmaName;
var result = from e in XElement.Load(XMLDocumentLocation).Elements(xmlns + ElementName)
             select new Object1
             {
                 Field1 = (string)e.Element(xmlns + "field1"),
                 Field2 = (string)e.Element(xmlns + "field2")
             };

var result2 = Enumerable.Distinct(result);
```

This code will vary for the different type of XML files that will be processed. But I then want to iterate though the code to check for various issues:

```
foreach (var w in result2)
{
    if (w.CheckIT())
    {
        //do something
    }  
}
```

What I would love is the final step to be in a method in the base class, and I can pass the 'var' varible into it from each child class.

Comment: Without knowing what "CheckIT()" wants to do, this will be really hard to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `w` is `Object1` (in the code as written above).  You can find this yourself by hovering your mouse over the `var` keyword and seeing the tooltip that Visual Studio shows you.

It's hard to tell from your question, but it sounds like the `CheckIt` method is defined on a base type of `Object1`.  If it is you can write your method to check them as

```
protected void CheckAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> result) where T : <base type with CheckIt method>
{
    foreach(var w in result)
    {
        if(w.CheckIt())
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ben,
Your assumption is correct. I will have Object2, Object3 etc.
The checkIt method is defined in the base class of each object.

Comment: Ben,
I can't seem ot get the code your provided to compile.
It's not liking the 
<base type with CheckIt method>  part of the code

Comment: Replace `<base type with CheckIt method>` with the name of base class that has the `CheckIt` method.

Comment: Doh! Sorry... was being a bit thick there... thanks! Will try that now.

Comment: Thanks so much Ben. It did just what I needed, and worked really well.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth noting that there is nothing like *"var" variable*. Any variable declared using the `var` keyword has an actual type (that is inferred by the compiler). You only don't have to write this type explicitly, but it still there (and the compiler replaces the `var` declaration with the actual type when it starts processing your code). This means that:

```
var n = 10 
// .. is exactly the same thing as:
int n = 10
```

And in your example:

```
var result = 
  from e in ... select new Object1 { ... };
// .. is exactly the same thing as:
IEnumerable<Object1> result = 
  from e in ... select new Object1 { ... };
```

The situation becomes more complicated if you use anonymous types (e.g. `new { Name="Test" }`) because these don't have a name that you could use in your code (so you're forced to work with them using `var`), but since your code doesn't contain anonymous types, this shouldn't be a problem for you. It is useful to realize that `var` is feature that's technically not realted to *anonymous types* in any way.

Answer (score 2):

Your objects are typed as `Object1`. You should be able to create a method like this:

```
private void CheckAll(IEnumerable<Object1> result)
{
    foreach(var w in result)
    {
        if(w.CheckIt())
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
CheckAll(result2);
```

If your functions all deal with different types and `CheckIt` is not established in a common base type, then this isn't possible (without reflection) in C# 3. C# 4 introduces [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736(VS.100).aspx) typing (specifically "[duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)" in this case) that will allow this.