# How to pass a var declared variable to a method (MathNET)

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

I would like to pass variable type of var to method, where var is some distribution

For example:

```
var t = new Chi(Double.Parse(textBox8.Text));
var t = new Cauchy(Double.Parse(textBox6.Text), Double.Parse(textBox7.Text));
```

and method:

```
drawDensity(var t) {...t.Sample()..t.Density()..}
```

Comment: This code wont compile.

Comment: As @Selman22 said, `var` isn't a type. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) for details. It sounds like you just want to use a generic? Something like `private void MyMethod<T>(T t) { //method body }`

Comment: Sounds like `drawDensity` Should accept a parameter that is an `IDistribution` interface or something along those lines.

Comment: Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2533663/2864740

Comment: IDistribution not compile

Comment: @Gugu You're going to need to write it, or figure out whatever appropriate interfaces might already exist for these types.

Answer (score 1):

First, the `var` is not a type.It is a way to tell the compiler to infer the type for you,instead of stating it explicitly.So specifying it as a parameter type is *invalid*.

Secondly, `drawDensity` method should take a parameter that is a common type between `Chi` and `Chaucy`, for example a common *interface* or a *base class*.If you want to pass both types to your method that is the preferred way.

If there is no common type that both type implements then it should be *object* or *dynamic*.

**Further reading**

- [`var` Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)
- [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)